# Custom Object Security, Portal Users

Tags: rest-api, customer-portal

My company has a Community Site which provides Support for our users.  The users of the Community Site are Portal Users (obviously).  The level of support provided is determined by the Portal Users Profile.

In addition to the Community Site, we have an external application (App) which allows the Portal Users to manage Records ( Custom Objects ).  It basically acts as a User Interface for CRUD operations on the Records.  The Portal Users are authenticated by the App via a ConnectedApp.  Record CRUD operations are performed via the REST API.

I would like to be able to establish a security hierarchy so that some Portal Users have read/write, while others have read-only access.  The Portal Users should be able to see all Records associated with their parent Account ( Records have an Account Id (custom) field ).

I cannot use the Role hierarchy becasue we cannot assign additional Profiles and Portal Users cannot be assigned Roles.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

My only thought at this point is to build a custom REST API function via Apex REST, but I've been told this won't work.
I imagined that I could set the Org Wid Default, Default External Access to 'Private' ( which would prevent a User from accessing any other User's Records ).  Then extending the access in the Apex REST class and using the 'without sharing' keyword on a data retrieval function.  All of the Records would be retrieved, then I could limit the Records that are returned to the User based on their Account, and any other Permission Sets that are applied to that Users.